# Java clipboardOwner Purpose?

Tags: java, clipboard

I wrote a Java application that copies a string to the system clipboard. The constructor uses

```
Clipboard.setContents(Transferable contents, ClipboardOwner owner)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html

I got it working fine but I am not sure what the ClipboardOwner does? Looking at the Java api does not really tell much info.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/ClipboardOwner.html

Oddly enough even passing a ClippboardOwner = null works. So I'm not exactly sure what the point of it is? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: +1 Good question. Maybe Oracle/Java has put it in place for the future, but I've often wondered this - I thought it was to do with the fact that you can have many local clipboards in the JVM, but @Sign seems to think differently?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application, or one of it's components implements `ClipboardOwner` interface in appropriate way, it can show you that the user copied some data to the system clipboard from another application, or from another component of your own application.
[See this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0382.html).

Comment: In another word, Clipboardowner is for registering callback for ownership lost event, that is, some change to the clipboard. This may be a reliable way to monitor clipboard copy event.

Answer (score 2):

When the next person puts something into the clipboard the owner you give to the clipboard will be told that they are no longer on the clipboard. There is only one known implementation and it is empty according to [this](http://kickjava.com/src/java/awt/datatransfer/StringSelection.java.htm). So it looks like a vestigial tail that is just sort of hanging out.

Comment: If standard API lacks implementations, nothing stops you from making your own.

Comment: I think the reason that the std lib doesn't supply any other implementations is that apps will generally want different behaviors. This is often the case for event listening interfaces e.g. AncestorListener has NO implementations in the std lib. It is provided so that the std lib can interact with app-specific code.

Comment: The one implementation also does nothing, see the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/datatransfer/StringSelection.java#StringSelection.lostOwnership%28java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard%2Cjava.awt.datatransfer.Transferable%29). There is only one method in the `ClipboardOwner` interface, namely `lostOwnership(..)`, and it is left empty by `StringSelection`.

Answer (score 0):

An example use-case is a terminal window implementation, where any selection gets automatically copied to the clipboard. The `lostOwnership(..)` callback may be used to unselect, so that the user knows that a selection is shown if and only if it is currently on the clipboard. This idiom is used e.g. in `rxvt` (which is not written in Java, however).