# Get source of data in clipboard

Tags: java, linux, clipboard

How can I know what is the source of data in clipboard?
For example when I copy something from Firefox to clipboard I want to get that the source is Firefox.
Is there any command to do that in Linux? Or is there a way to do that in Java?

Also, is there any way to track were the user pasted the data.

I want to detect if for example the user try to copy important data from organization's system, then s/he try to paste it some where else.

Thanks in advance for any help (:

Answer (score 0):

It's not a language issue, it's an API issue.  In Windows, the GetClipboardOwner() API call usually indicates the application that last updated the clipboard (via a handle).  It's not 100% reliable. For example, if the application has terminated, then it will be null.
This function exists in Java but seems to be even less reliable, and may be mostly unused, according to this post:
[Java clipboardOwner Purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421007/java-clipboardowner-purpose)

I think your best solution is to use the presence/absence of various clipboard formats to look for evidence.  Simple formats like TEXT won't help, but complex formats like RTF and HTML will reveal clues.  On Windows, there is a format for "html fragments" called CF_HTML, which has a header that looks different from one browser to the next.  I would imagine that something similar exits with Java/Linux?  Looking at the docs, there's something called a DataFlavor, that seems to have a very rich set of properties such as mimetype.  It's possible that you could get a "fingerprint" of FireFox by looking at the attributes of each dataflavor present when copying.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to determine the source of the data in the clipboard in Java (for Linux I'm not sure but I doubt it).

To ensure that sensible Data does not leave your application do not allow the data to be copied or keep the data in an application internal clipboard and do not forward it to the system clipboard. In Java you have the control over your data being copied to the system clipboard or not.

If you use an application internal clipboard then be aware that a user could copy the sensible data first to a target that allows copying the content to the system clipboard and then copy it further out of your application.

Comment: Is there any way to know the source in other programming languages.

Comment: @Dareen I doubt it. Also knowing the source is not enough as a programs name may change and also all installed applications must obey your idea to let it work. So don't copy sensible information to the system clipboard.